# Getting the contents of Chrome's console with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, console, screen-scraping

First time poster. Currently trying to work on a project but I am having an issue with iframes. I'm making an extension for Chrome, and part of its functionality right now is to be fetching any shapes/borders on a page. Unfortunately, that also includes ones within iframes. I'm currently stuck because I cannot get around security policies from Cross-Domain sources.

I was wondering, however, if it is possible to create a function that displays what the Chrome console does when I hit "inspect element" on a page... I tried to make a console function called "save" that would automatically download a file of anything output to the log, but the output for the iframe's HTML is blank except for its tag...

When I am inspecting an element on the page, I can see the contents of that iframe just fine. Is there anyway to just get the actual text from Inspect Element and store that? I know this may be silly, but I genuinely have no idea. I am pretty new to JavaScript. I just need to match up script tags for shapes for part of the extension's functionality.

I'm assuming that this is going to end up being impossible, but I figured I'd ask. I'm also assuming that this inspect element functionality is something that only the browser can work with. But hey, maybe there's a way. Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, you can't do that (and messing with the devtools would be a bad idea anyway), but your extension should be permitted to a) take full screenshots if that's what you need b) inject JS code into the iframed page

Comment: @Bergi I haven't had much luck injecting my scripts into iframed pages. I test it and it doesn't show the script in the iframe's contents when I use inspect element.